# Place a div containing video over a jpeg

Tags: css

I'm super new to coding so apologies if this frustrates anyone!

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I'm trying to lay a video (actually a shortcode) over a jpeg, like this;

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/617x176q90/540/OJCIR1.jpg

Then place a video thumbnail (that opens into a lightbox when clicked) on the grey area.  Here's my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">
    <img src=".../uploads/2015/01/watch.jpg" style="z-index:-1" />
    <div class="videodiv">[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="G7z74BvLWUg" width="640" height="480" auto_thumb="1"]
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
div.videodiv {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

As I'm sure you can tell I'm brutally savaging this code from tips found online.

Any help would be massively appreciated, and how do I insert code into these topics?!

Sorry!

Comment: The best way I think you could do this, is put the video inside a div, and set that div to have an absolute position, with the image the background of a parent div, which has a relative position. Then tinker with the CSS for alignment.

Comment: Wowzers, quick response!  Thanks everyone.  Lee, your idea worked and with some tinkering it's exactly where I need it to be, so thank you!  With two other answers however, how do I know which is best practice?  They all look good to me?!

Comment: I would personally favour @Skatox answer, as it makes use of classes and tidier markup, and is a more idealistic way of how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks @Lee :) I'll post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's better to set the image as background and then align the video to the place where you want it, something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="videodiv">[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="G7z74BvLWUg" width="640" height="480" auto_thumb="1"]
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 640px; //Change it to image's width
    height: 480px; //change it to image's height
    background: url(.../uploads/2015/01/watch.jpg) #fff;
}  

div.videodiv {
    right: 20px; //distance from right border to gray rectangle border 
    top: 10px; //distance from top border to gray rectangle top border
    position: absolute; //let total control of the position of the video
}
```

Comment: OK following Lee's suggestion I've dumped him in favour of @Skatox!  I've added all that and changed my wrapper w and h but I can't seem to get the video to move when I change right and top values?

Does it matter that I put it all in a <div style="float: right;">

Comment: OK I answered my own question!  I deleted my float right and put it in the CSS for div.wrapper, then the video top and right worked fine!  All fixed!  Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute; rule in the video and position relative in the image, and then play with the position right and top in the video

CSS EXAMPLE

```
div.videodiv {
    right: 0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute
} 

img{
position: relative;
z-index: 998;
}
```